# How to ignore default roles in drupal roles

Tags: users

I don't want to show the default roles to end user and want to ignore anonymous user and authenticated user. How can I remove these two roles from roles array. Shall I hard code the role names and rid say as in example below?

I have used this code.

```
$ignore = array(1 => 'anonymous user', 2 => 'authenticated user');
$roles = user_roles();
$roles =  array_diff($roles, $ignore);
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you asking "Here's this code that works - will it always work?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call [user_roles(TRUE)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_roles/7), the function will not return the anonymous user role.

Drupal always sets the role ID for anonymous user role, and the authenticated user role to the value of the constants `DRUPAL_ANONYMOUS_RID`, and `DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID`.

The following code is executed by [user_install()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.install/function/user_install/7) in Drupal 7, and similar code is executed by [system_install()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.install/function/system_install/6) in Drupal 6.

```
// Built-in roles.
  $rid_anonymous = db_insert('role')
    ->fields(array('name' => 'anonymous user', 'weight' => 0))
    ->execute();
  $rid_authenticated = db_insert('role')
    ->fields(array('name' => 'authenticated user', 'weight' => 1))
    ->execute();

  // Sanity check to ensure the anonymous and authenticated role IDs are the
  // same as the drupal defined constants. In certain situations, this will
  // not be true.
  if ($rid_anonymous != DRUPAL_ANONYMOUS_RID) {
    db_update('role')
      ->fields(array('rid' => DRUPAL_ANONYMOUS_RID))
      ->condition('rid', $rid_anonymous)
      ->execute();
  }
  if ($rid_authenticated != DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID) {
    db_update('role')
      ->fields(array('rid' => DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID))
      ->condition('rid', $rid_authenticated)
      ->execute();
  }
```

The following code works also in Drupal 5; the `$roles` array will not contain information about the anonymous user, and the authenticated user roles.

```
$roles = user_roles(TRUE);
unset($roles[DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID]);
```